# How can I combine these two statements?

Tags: perl, xampp, cgi

I'm currently trying to insert data into a database from a text boxes, $enter / $enter2 being where the text is being written.

The database consists of three columns ID, name and nametwo

ID is auto incrementing and works fine

Both statements work fine on their own, but because they are being issued separately the first leaves nametwo blank and the second leaves name blank.

I've tried combining both but haven't had much luck, hope someone can help.

```
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO $table(name) VALUES ('".$enter."')");
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO $table(nametwo) VALUES ('".$enter2."')");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read database manual.

The query should be:

```
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO $table(name,nametwo) VALUES ('".$enter."', '".$enter2."')");
```

Comment: Thankyou, very much, I know i tried something like that, not sure what i was missing

Comment: Don't quote strings for db statements yourself. Better use prepared statements and provide the variables to the statement handlers.

Comment: This is horrible on so many levels. Why not use `prepare` and `execute` over `do`? It allows you to use placeholders and avoid interpolation, preventing sql-injection attacks. Also, you don't have to break up the string and use the concatenation operator `.` to interpolate scalar variables, you just put them in: `VALUES ('$enter', ...` (but dont do that here, like I said).

Comment: @TLP, Re "Why not use `prepare` and `execute` over `do`?", Needlessly wordy. Re " It allows you to use placeholders", Same with `do`.

Answer (score 5):

To paraphrase what others have said:

```
   my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO $table(name,nametwo) values (?,?)");
   $sth->execute($enter, $enter2);
```

So you don't have to worry about quoting.

Comment: or `$dbh->do("INSERT INTO $table(name,nametwo) values (?,?)",undef,$enter,$enter2)` if we are only doing this once.

Comment: Also note that this code will not work as is. You  need to do `my $sth = $dbh->prepare(...)` and `$sth->execute`

Comment: Except you still interpolate `$table` instead of using `$dbh->quote_identifier($table)`

Answer (score 0):

The SQL syntax is

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (
           name_one,
           name_two
       ) VALUES (
           "value_one",
           "value_two"
       )
```

---

Your way of generating SQL statements is very fragile. For example, it will fail if the table name is `Values` or the value is `Jester's`.

Solution 1:

```
$dbh->do("
   INSERT INTO ".$dbh->quote_identifier($table_name)."
              name_one,
              name_two
          ) VALUES (
              ".$dbh->quote($value_one).",
              ".$dbh->quote($value_two)."
          )
");
```

Solution 2: Placeholders

```
$dbh->do(
   "   INSERT INTO ".$dbh->quote_identifier($table_name)."
                  name_one,
                  name_two
              ) VALUES (
                  ?, ?
              )
    ",
    undef,
    $value_one,
    $value_two,
);
```